# uib-carousel has height 0

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using:

- angularjs 1.5.3
- ui-bootstrap 1.3.2

This is my template:

```
<div id="content" class="center">
    <div id="title">
        <uib-carousel active="true" interval="5000" ng-if="slides && slides.length">
            <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.name">
                <img ng-src="{{ slide.image }}" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>{{ slide.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somewhere in my code I perform a call (with a working service I used many times) like this:

```
Index.controller('Index.Main', ['$scope', '$sce', 'MyService', function($scope, $sce, myService) {
    $scope.slides = [];
    myService.loadStuff($scope, ..., function(){
        console.log($scope.slides);
    }, function(data, status) {
        console.log('Could not retrieve stuff');
    }).update();
}]);
```

Which can be detailed as follows:

1. MyServices calls `$http.get` behind the scenes.
2. An array of slides will be shown by console when there is an http success. Right now this is the case.
3. An error message will be shown by console when there is an http error. Right not it is NOT the case.
4. Finally, the images are attached correctly to the dom. I can be sure about this because I can inspect it in my browser. **however** the carousel height (and contents height) is 0.

What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually forgot to correctly specify the index property. If there is no index to match against, then there is no way to tell which image is active. When no image is active, the container has height 0

Comment: In my case the index property was `index=$index` and _not_ `index=slide.id` :)

Answer (score 0):

From uibootstrap doc:
[image]

As you can see, you need to declare the height of the carousel in the container div